# XML Schema ComplexType Attribute Ref

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, complextype

I'm having some trouble with assigning an attribute to a complexType in my XML schema. a cut down version of my schema is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://xml-test.com"
    xmlns="http://xml-test.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!--++++++++++ ELEMENT DEFINTIONS ++++++++++-->

<xs:element name="DataRoot" type="RootDataType"/>

<!--++++++++++ TYPE DEFINTIONS ++++++++++-->

<!-- Document Root -->
<xs:complexType name="RootDataType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="ValueSet" type="ValuesType"/>
    </xs:sequence>  

    <!-- Attributes -->
    <xs:attribute name="index" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Value Set Type: A type representing a series of data values -->
<xs:complexType name="ValuesType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="FishCount" type="FishCountType"/>
    </xs:sequence>          

    <!-- Attributes -->
    <xs:attribute name="catcher" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>


<!-- Simple Fish Count type -->
<xs:simpleType name="SimpleFishCountType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:totalDigits value="3"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- Fish Count type -->
<xs:complexType name="FishCountType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="SimpleFishCountType">
                <xs:attribute ref="interpolation"/>
        </xs:extension>                        
    </xs:simpleContent>                
</xs:complexType>

<!--++++++++++ ATTRIBUTE DEFINTIONS ++++++++++-->

<!-- Attribute to specify interpolation method -->
<xs:attribute name="interpolation">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

An explanation: I've got a "DataRoot" element, which can contain 1 or more "ValueSet" elements. My ValueSet type contains one element, FishCount, which is a complex type, FishCountType.

FishCountType is composed of the simpletype SimpleFishCount, which is based on a decimal number with restrictions, and an attribute, "interpolation".

The test XML file I'm using is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<DataRoot index="1"
          xmlns="http://xml-test.com"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml-test.com test-001.xsd">

    <ValueSet catcher="CaptainBirdsEye">
         <FishCount interpolation="0">12.3</FishCount>
    </ValueSet>
</DataRoot>
```

Using this validator: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UiC9UpK0KSo

I see that both the XSD and XML are valid and well formed, but when validating the XML against the XSD, I get this error:

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 9, 36: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 36; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'interpolation' is not allowed to appear in element 'FishCount'.
```

It seems the reference to the 'interpolation' attribute in 'FishCountType' is incorrect somehow, but I can't figure it out. If I define the interpolation attribute inline within FishCountType type, and change it to xs:integer, it all works nicely.

What am I doing wrong here? Can I use a custom attribute in this way?

Any help appreciated, I've scratched my head nearly bald.

SOLVED thanks to @Michael Kay

This is what I've gone with:

```
    <xs:attributeGroup name="interpolation">
      <xs:attribute name="interpolation">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a namespace issue. You've declared interpolation to be in the target namespace of the schema.

The usual workaround to this problem if you want to reuse attribute definitions is to declare the attribute using a local declaration within a global attribute group. As a local declaration it is then (by default) in no namespace.